# CMake: build fails when compiling a C++ shared lib depending on MPI

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, mpi, static-libraries

## Problem overview

I'm using CMake to build a project which contains a library based on MPI. The lib has to be built as both shared and static. When I build the project on my Fedora 20 system, everything goes without problem. When I build it on a Mac OS X El Capitan system, the building process fails with an error of the type:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

## Additional remarks

- I cannot activate the option forcing automatic compilation of libs as both shared and static because this specific library is the only one that needs to be built as both.
- Forcing the replacement of the C++ compiler command by the MPI wrapper (`mpicxx`) results in a successful build but completely breaks CLion's code analysis.

## Minimal (non)working example

File: `MPILib.h`

```
#include <mpi.h>
void MPILib();
```

File: `MPILib.c`

```
#include "MPILib.h"
void MPILib() { MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); }
```

File: `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

enable_language(CXX)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

add_library(mpilib_shared SHARED MPILib.cpp MPILib.h)
add_library(mpilib_static STATIC MPILib.cpp MPILib.h)
```

Build commands:

- `cmake .`
- `make mpilib_static` (succeeds)
- `make mpilib_shared` (fails)

Comment: I just found out what could be the beginning of an answer: I think I am missing a linking instruction `target_link_libraries(mpicom_shared ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})`. Which leads me to the subsequent question: why would forgetting linking be a problem for shared and not for static?